# bash: ifconfig: command not found под обычным пользователем

Tags: linux, ifconfig

`man ifconfig` - работает. А просто `ifconfig` под **обычным** пользователем в отличии от пользователя с *root* правами выдаёт ошибку :

> bash: ifconfig: command not found

Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: ifconfig обычно лежит в /sbin или /usr/sbin А этих каталогов по умолчанию не перечислено в PATH для обычного пользователя. Так то либо сделать ссылку на ifconfig из досутпных в PATH папок (/bin, /usr/bin и т.п.) или добавить нужную папку явно в PATH. остается вопрос захочет ли он работать под пользователем без sudo ...

Comment: это не влияет на безопасность

Comment: по моему, такое поведение только в федоре или я не прав?

Comment: в убунте нет, в генте нет, в сюсе вроде также нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что *ifconfig* находится в /sbin или /usr/sbin. А этих каталогов по умолчанию не перечислено в PATH для обычного пользователя.

Фактически, можно запустить команду `ifconfig` в качестве обычного пользователя, если вы запустите ее с ее абсолютным путем, найти который поможет команда `which ifconfig` :

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Но **только** для отображения настроек интерфейса *Ethernet*, а не для изменения самих настроек, для которых вам необходимо получить привилегии *root*.

Чтоб исправить на старое поведение, где ifconfig был доступен пользователю сделайте ссылку:

```
ln -s `which ifconfig` /usr/local/bin/ifconfig
```

Comment: а вообще программы *ifconfig* может и не быть в системе по умолчанию. она [совершенно не подходит для целей диагностики сетевой подсистемы](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712) современных версий (выше или равной второй, вышедшей лет 17 назад) программы linux. корректно работает программа *ip*, которой и следует пользоваться.

Comment: Только лучше в *~/bin*